# Wait Page while Credit Card Processing happens

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, credit-card

HI Im building a website where we are doing credit card transactions. Im building the web app in Asp.net using C#. My question is while the credit card transaction happens behind the scene with the webservice - how do i show a page to the customer stating that "Credit Card processing is happening please wait".
I just want to show a page that the credit card transaction is happening so that the customer doesnt hit the submit button multiple times. can some one tell me how i can achieve this.

Comment: Please avoid adding signature (it is already in your name) and "thank you notes" (upvote/accept good ansvers instead). Also heck your shift key - seems to be working semi-randomly.

Answer (score 1):

The best option may be to do an asynchronous web service call. There's an article on [Steve Wellens'](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/) ASP.NET blog describing [how to do Async web service calls from a web page](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/04/02/calling-web-service-functions-asynchronously-from-a-web-page.aspx).

Comment: HI i have no problem with the service it works fine. i get the required output too. All i need is when the processing is happening like you see in any ecommerce application - we get a page stating that " your transaction is being processed - please wait". i want to be showing something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DIV` tag in your page that contains all the text, graphics and styling you want with the `display` property set to `none` and disable the submit button. In the `click` event of the button that starts the long running process set the `display` property to `block` to display the message.  When the long running process completes, the page it returns wil replace this page. You will have to work out the details for yourself.